# Why does subtracting days not allow me to go over 27

Tags: javascript

Whenever I run the code The diffDays will only go to the count of 27 and then transfer over to 0 instead of 31 as the condition says.

When I run the code the diffDays will not go past the 27 mark. It will add 1 to the month and reset itself to 0.

```js
var selection = document.getElementById("dateSelected");
var result = document.getElementById("days");
var selectedDate;
function differentDays() {
    selectedDate = new Date(selection.value);
    var date = new Date();
    var chosenYear = selectedDate.getFullYear();
    var chosenDate = selectedDate.getDate();
    var chosenMonth = selectedDate.getMonth();
    var todayYear = date.getFullYear();
    var todayDate = date.getDate();
    var todayMonth = date.getMonth();
    var diffDate = Math.abs((todayDate - chosenDate) - 1);
    var diffYear = Math.abs(todayYear - chosenYear);
    var diffMonth = Math.abs(todayMonth - chosenMonth);
    if (diffDate > 31){
        diffMonth += 1;
        diffDate = 0;
        }
    if (diffMonth > 12){
        diffYear += 1;
        diffMonth = 0;
        }
    result.innerHTML = "Years: " + diffYear  + " Months: " + diffMonth + " Days: " + diffDate;

}
function createEventListener() {
    var submitButton = document.getElementById("determineDate");
    if (submitButton.addEventListener) {
        submitButton.addEventListener("click", differentDays, false);
    } else if (submitButton.attachEvent) {
        submitButton.attachEvent("onclick", differentDays);
    }
    document.getElementById("dateSelected").value = "";
    //clear last starting value on reload
    document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = "";
    //clear previous results on reload
}
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("load", createEventListener, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent("onload", createEventListener);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="dateSelected">
      Select a date
    </label>
    <input type="date" id="dateSelected" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="button">
    <button type="button" id="determineDate">Find day</button>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
     <p>Difference of Dates</p>
    <p id="days"></p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```